# Observer to fire on customer login Page Url (baseUrl."customer/account/login") magento 2

Tags: event-observer, customer, magento2.3, url, login

I want to fire **observer** on customer login Page url(baseUrl."`customer/account/login`") magento 2.

I tried `customer_login` event but it's firing after customer login.

> etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="redirect_to_ccp_login" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\RedirectccpLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Observer\RedirectccpLogin.php

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class RedirectccpLogin implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface 
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $_responseFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
         \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,
         \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $this->_logger->info("ccp customer login fire");

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you try changing your classname `Redirectccplogin` instead of `RedirectccpLogin`, i know that's silly but someone got solved just because of this.

Answer (score 1):

> I overrided `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login` Controller
>
> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Customer\Login" />

</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Controller\Customer\Login.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Login extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login
{
      /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;
    protected $_logger;
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $_responseFactory;

    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
         Session $customerSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context,$customerSession,$resultPageFactory);
    }

    /**
     * Customer login form page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {

       $this->_logger->info("cpp customer login  using controller.");

    }
}
```

> Above code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Plugin,

> Create a di.xml file **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="customer_login_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Create a Plugin file **app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Customer/LoginPost.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer;

class LoginPost
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_response = $context->getResponse();
    }

    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $proceed)
    {           
        $login =  $this->_request->getPost('login');     

        // before login check condition

        $returnValue = $proceed();            

        // after login check condition

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: this plugin also working after customer login time only but i want to redirect to some other url once we hit our magento baseUrl.(“customer/account/login”).

Comment: i changed class RedirectccpLogin to Redirectccplogin but no result